# Residually finite Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups

My question is about the definition of residually finite Lie groups and their properties. I couldn't find any reference that contains exactly the meaning of residual finiteness of a given Lie group.

Comment: For a topological group you have a priori two notions: residually finite as discrete group (which also mean residually finite as topological group, allowing non-Hausdorff finite quotients), and residually finite as topological group, which more properly would mean residually (finite Hausdorff), and means that the intersection of open normal subgroups of finite index is trivial. This is a stronger condition. Actually, a non-discrete Lie group is never residually finite even as discrete group, as it contains an isomorphic copy of $\mathbf{Q}$, so there is not much to say.

Comment: Surely Lie groups are almost the opposite of residually finite groups? For instance the additive group of $\mathbb{R}$ has no finite quotients.

Comment: Thank you YCor for explaining. I was so confused about this notion of residually finite Lie groups.